# Creating SQL table using C#

Tags: c#, sql, odbc

I would like to create two SQL tables using C#, within a loop. Each table is different, and has its column names stored in an array. Each array of column names is actually obtained from the header of a csv file.

```
 ### fnames is an array of file paths (2 csv files)
 foreach string f in fnames)
 {
      ## snip
      using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(f))
      {
           string header = read.line();  ## This is the array of table columns
      }
      string tab = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f);
      string query = @"create table "+ tab + ..."; #I am not sure how to write the column names and types dynamically
 }
```

Imagine that:

- The columns for table 1 are : Date (datetime), Value (int)
- The columns for table 2 are : Date (datetime), ID (varchar(255)), Return (int)

Note that the two tables have different columns with different types.
Would you have any suggestion as to how to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: What does `header` contain exactly?

Comment: For example: `header = {"Date", "ID"}` for table 1.

Comment: It all depends on how you are determining the types of the columns, work out how you are going to get a list of column names and types from your headers string then come back and tackle the creating of the table.

Comment: @Mariam then how do you know the type ?

Comment: That's exactly the problem. Let's simplify and let the first column of each table be `datetime` and all the other columns be `varchar(255)`. Is there a way of doing this then?

Comment: @Mariam break the problem apart, focus on getting a object that is a `List<Somthing>` that defines your header (it could be as simple as `List<String>` that just has the header names or a custom class that holds the name, data type, max length, ect...), then you can write a 2nd piece of code that takes that list in and builds your create table statement, it would be a simple foreach loop and a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should break the problem apart, first you need to get a list of objects that define your column headers, after you have that you can loop over that list and build the query.

```
class HeaderInfo
{
    public HeaderInfo(string header)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Parse out your header info here and populate the class")
    }

    public string Name {get; private set;}
    public string TypeInfo {get; private set;}
}

private List<HeaderInfo> ParseHeader(string header)
{
    var headerInfo = new List<HeaderInfo>();
    string[] headerItems = //Split your header line in to indvidual items some how
    foreach(headerItem in headerItems)
    {
         headerInfo.Add(new HeaderInfo(headerItem));
    }
    return headerInfo;
}

private string TableString(List<HeaderInfo> headerInfo)
{
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

     foreach(var info in headerInfo)
     {
         sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1}, ", info.Name, info.TypeInfo);
     }

     sb.Remove(sb.Length -2, 2); //Remove the last ", "

     return sb.ToString();
}

private void YourMethod(string[] fnames)
{
    ### fnames is an array of file paths (2 csv files)
    foreach string f in fnames)
    {
         ## snip
         List<HeaderInfo> headerInfo;
         using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(f))
         {
              string headerLine = read.line();  ## This is the array of table columns
              headerInfo = ParseHeader(headerLine);
         }
         string tab = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f);
         string query = String.Format(@"create table [{0}] ({1})", tab, TableString(headerInfo));
    }
}
```